Размер шрифта, относительно высоты блока в %
Есть блок, высота которого задана в процентах. Блоке есть текст...
Вопрос, как привязать размер шрифта к высоте блока, возможно? Без js, только css

Интересно, а если высота блока будет 100рх то какой будет размер шрифта?

Вообще есть em,rem и целый набор способов как адаптировать шрифт...не надо выдумывать...все годные способы уже выдуманы и протестированы

@РезидентКазахстана, а что не так со 100px?

Можно, но только в современных браузерах и с дополнительным элементом. Также есть побочные эффекты, связанные с использованием контейнера, но в вопросе они не запрещены. caniuse


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

section {
  container-type: size;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

div {
  font-size: 100cqb;
  line-height: 1;
}

p {
  font-size: 50cqb;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
<section>
  <div>123</div>
</section>

<section>
  <p>123<br>456</p>
</section>




С крупными размерами всё ясно, не ясно если блок сожмётся по высоте до 3% какой должен быть размеи шрифта

@РезидентКазахстана, ну шрифт тоже сожмётся. Но вполне может быть, что блок не может так сжиматься. Это уже в конкретном месте надо смотреть.
